# encrypt an 8 letter word python, what's wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii

```
def code_char(c, key):
    return chr(ord(c)+int(key))

def code_block(word,key):
    letters = list(word)
    keys = list(key)
    for letter in letters:
        for digit in keys:
            coded = code_char(letter, digit)
    return coded

print(code_block('abcdefgh', '12121212'))
```

I am trying to encrypt the code block input using Ascii tables etc.

Can't get it to work! What is wrong?

Get the error:

> TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found

Just a student so don't go ham plz

Anyone?

Comment: Ah, I get that, but I tried using the list functions to split it up, no?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I misread. Answering now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce your error, for me your code prints `j`.

The problem is that you're assigning the "encrypted" character to `coded`, and therefore are overwriting the previously "encrypted" character. One way to fix that would be to make `coded` a list:

```
def code_block(word,key):
    letters = list(word)
    keys = list(key)
    coded = []
    for letter, digit in zip(letters, keys):
        coded.append(code_char(letter, digit))
    return "".join(coded)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, however, I have ended up with

bcbcbcbccdcdcdcddedededeefefefeffgfgfgfgghghghghhihihihiijijijij

as an output, I was expecting ’bddffhhj’

Comment: Ah, right, I didn't look at the rest of the code. This happened because for every letter you iterated over every digit, when you really want to look at them in pairs. For that, you should use `zip`, as shown in my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! Glad to be rid of the error messages. I have never used the zip function but it looks handy. Thanks again.